# emacs 25 doesn't load my .emacs config file

Tags: emacs, emacs25

```
Fedora 24

emacs 25
```

I have installed Fedora 24 and installed emacs 25 that comes with Fedora.

Before I was using Fedora 22 with emacs 24.3.1 and had my .emacs file in `~/.emacs` in the root of my home directory. Emacs would load that without any problem.

Now that I am using emacs 25 my `.emacs` doesn't load anymore. Just wondering has anything changed with it, to get it to load my .emacs file. My .emacs is in my `~/.emacs` of my home directory.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Does running Emacs with `emacs --debug-init` show you any errors? If not, what does `C-h v user-init-file` tell you?

Comment: Thanks phils for the tip. The reason it doesn't load if because there are some things it can't find in the .emacs file as I have just installed a new OS. --debug-init did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `.emacs` "file"?

The way to place `.emacs` "file" in the home directory is obsolete, placing
`.emacs.d` "directory" in the home directory and placing `init.el` "file" in it is considered as modern customization I will.

Because by placing the init.el file it makes it possible

- to byte compile. (Byte compile as `init.elc`)
- to manage changes to the `.emacs.d` by git easy.
- ...

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init